# Cache key organization problem

Tags: java, programming-languages, theory, ehcache

My entity has two unique ids (yes this is wrong but it is a requirement). I want to organize a cache of such instances. The search in cache could be made by id1 OR id2 OR id1 and id2. Search by both id1 and id2 is ok - I will make composite key. But how to deal with just search by one of ids. What should be the cache key? I'm using ehcache.

I have a situation where several key may refer the same
object.

Like ehcache does not suport this feature, the same
object will be stored for each key (n instances of the
same object, where n is the number of diferent keys
that that object may be refered from).

At some point i have the knowledge to calculate the
other keys, but not before i need them.

Situation :

GEN KEY (1)
Check if object is in cache (2)
TRUE : Retreve it

FALSE : Process the new object (3)
Place it in ehcache
return OBJECT

At point (1) just know one of the keys. At the point
(3) there is the possibility to know all keys that the
object may have associated to it in ehcache.
The problem is that the keys are needed at point (2).

Thx

Comment: I found one bug for ehache with the same situation as mine that was closed as won't fix with comments that there is some kind of index utility called jofti, but it is dead i guess. Maybe some know what patterns does this jotfi use to implement search in cache by multiple keys?

Comment: http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/EHC-268?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for ehcache, but I've been having a similar problem for `HashMap` used as cache. I simply put each value twice in the Map, it's not that expensive and it worked well.

Because of my keys being of different types, I used `Map<Object, V>`.

Comment: I yes i see, but my entity takes much memory to cache it twice)

Comment: The entity gets stored just once, doesn't it? I see it for ehcache doesn't. So use two caches, the additional is for mapping the other id on the one use by the real cache. But it's twice slower due to the two accesses instead of one, which may or may not matter.

Comment: yes this is the problem that is matters :) so i'm still searching a solution to have only one cache of objects to ability to search by multiple keys.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use two Maps.  One for each id set, but both would point to the same set of values.

If the search is on id1 just lookup the value in the first map, if on id2, just lookup in the second map.  If you need to search both, lookup both values and see if the values are identical.

**Updated based on updates to your question and comments below:**
Use both keys in your ecache. Yes this will take up more space and there might be times that the object you are looking for is already in the cache under the other key.  However, the cache should store common looked up keys. It should not care that the value might exist under another key.  So I would not stress yourself with trying to optimize your cache to lookup based on two keys.

Comment: maybe you some kind of cache patterns that could be applied to such situation?

Comment: @user, I don't quite understand your question in the above comment.  Could you rephrase it or give an example?

Comment: Sorry for mistakes in comment, i was asking you about some other patterns or tools that can resolve this situation)

Comment: @user, could you explain your situation more, especially what makes using a Map undesirable so that we can understand what you are looking for out of a solution.   Thanks

Comment: the problem is that my ehcache cleans cache after 15 minutes of inactivity (this is a requirement due to the quantity and size of objects), and creation of additional map that links keys makes it grows all the time in size, so if i have several millions of objects the cache of objects will be at some size and map of keys will be very big.  I will update header of the story with sample in one minute.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want you can do it by transitivity storing not only the object in the cache, but storing also the index that points to your object using each of the keys.
e.g.:
cache["key1"]=theIndex;
cache["key2"]=theIndex;
cache[theIndex]=object;

So, when you request for cache["key1"] you'd get an index (you have to know it's an index), and then get the actual object using that index.

The code could go something like:

```
 public class CacheUtil {

   ... any necessary code here

   public static void put(String key, Serializable obj) {
    if (obj instance of Cacheable) { 
      //Cacheable interface identifies the cacheable object that has the getKeys method
      String[] keys = obj.getKeys();
      if (keys != null && keys.length > 0) {

        for (String myKey : keys) {
          //CacheIndex identifies the index
          cache.put(new Element(myKey, new CacheIndex(hashCode))); 
        }
        key = hashCode(keys); //change the key. Can be a hashcode of the keys
      }
    }

    cache.put(new Element(key, obj));
  }

  public static Serializable get(String key) {

    Serializable obj = cache.get(key);

    return ((null != serializable) && (serializable instanceof CacheIndex)) ?
            get(((CacheIndex)serializable).getIndex(), area) : obj;
  }

}
```